# What is the best way to load image for UIImage in resultBlock of ALAssetLibray?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I am trying to load image for UIImage in resultBlock of ALAssetLibray.
it works, but sometime i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the resultBlock. i guess it is around asynchronous-problems...  now i can't understand the best way to load image. my code in the following. anyone know what's wrong.

```
func loadImage(url: String!) {

    let asseturl = URL(string: url)!

    self.assetsLibrary.asset(
        for: asseturl,
        resultBlock: { (asset:ALAsset?) -> Void in

            print("ok")
            let cgi = asset!.thumbnail()
            let img = UIImage(cgImage: cgi!.takeRetainedValue()
            self.image = img // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here

        },                
        failureBlock: { (error: Error?) -> Void in

        }       
    )


}
```

Comment: FYI - Unless you need to support iOS 7, you should be using the newer Photos framework, not the old AssetsLibrary framework.

Comment: Just to put "unless you need to support iOS 7" in context: [Apple's measurement of iOS version adoption](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) shows 92% of devices on iOS **9** or newer as of 11/28/2016. (It doesn't break down what of the remaining 8% are iOS 7 vs iOS 8, but really... how worthwhile is it to you to put lots of extra effort into supporting less than 8% of your potential users? And that number isn't getting bigger.)

Comment: ok.  i will use Photos framework.  thank you very much the iOS version adoption.  it's encouraged me to focus on iOS 9 later.